# WCF Service reference in WCF not getting method type correct

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

WCF service library specifies:

```
[OperationContract]
void SaveData(IDictionary visitorData);
```

Adding a service reference in the consuming MVC project to the wcf library (must uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" to make it generate code) causes it to generate the following in Reference.cs:

```
public void SaveData(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, object> visitorData) {
    base.Channel.SaveData(visitorData);
}
```

As a result, when I call

```
visitorActions.SaveData(requestInfo);
```

(with `requestInfo` of type `IDictionary`) I get, to my utter lack of surprise, the following compiler error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IDictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'...

Yes, I can go in and change the code to explicitly say `IDictionary` but `Reference.cs` is autogenerated and the next time I update from the service, my changes will be gone.

So what gives?

Comment: Can you choose a non-generic collection type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx Also if you can share the service contract's assembly with your client project then just use a channel factory and avoid svcutil

Comment: _To specify list or dictionary collection types for a WCF client, select the types from the Collection type and Dictionary collection type lists._

I see that now. Ugh. I'm grabbing the Request.Browser.Capabilities object (which is of type `IDictionary`). I suppose I can cast or throw that into a generic one.

Wow, can't use an enumerable dictionary type. Seems a little short sighted. If you pop this up as an answer, I'll repost the relevant part of what you links and mark it as an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Configure Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx) dialog box enables you to configure the behavior of generated proxies. This includes options for configuring what types are used for collections and dictionaries. If `IDictionary` isn't in there you might not be able to generate a proxy that uses it from within Visual Studio.

But remember that the generated clients simply exchange data in an agreed upon format. If you can get your hands on an assembly containing your service contract (or a service contract in the right format) you can use a channel factory to generate a client, instead. The format of data sent over-the-wire will be the same and therefore compatible with your service.

You can see a simple example of channel factories [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/channel-factory-in-wcf/).

Comment: _To specify list or dictionary collection types for a WCF client, select the types from the Collection type and Dictionary collection type lists._

Changing the data contract method signature to a Dictionary instead of an IDictionary resolves the issue. Casting IDictionary to Dictionary is another matter altogether but that's another story for another time.

Thanks

Comment: @MetalPhoenix If you're not familiar with channel factories I'd recommend taking a look at them. First time I realised what they could do (no more Reference.cs) `mind == blown`

Comment: I'll dive deeper into that then, thanks for the prod. I'm sure my mind will explode as well.